# How to delete from a database?

Tags: mysql, database-design, sql-delete

I know of two ways to delete data from a database table

- DELETE it forever
- Use a flag like isActive/isDeleted

Now the problem with isActive is that I have to track everywhere in my SQL queries that whether the record is active or not. Using DELETE however gets rid of the data forever.

What would be the best way to backup this data?

Assuming I have multiple tables in a database, should I have a common function which just backs everything up and stores it in another table (in XML probably?) or is there any other way.

I am using MySQL but am curious about techniques used in other DBs as well.

Comment: people may be nice enough to give you code snippets if you tell us what DB software you're using :)

Comment: Using MySQL. Isn't everybody else? :P

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Replace the table with a view that hides the inactive items.

Or write a trigger on DELETE that backs up the row to an archive table.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a trigger that fires on deleting records to back them up into some kind of graveyard table.

Answer (score 2):

You could use an isDeleted column and defien a view which selects all columns except isDeleted with the condition isDeleted=false. Then have all your stps work only with the view.

Answer (score 1):

You could maintain a history table, where you back the record up and time stamp

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest reasons for *not* deleting data is that it may be required for a relation - for example the the user may decide to delete an old customer from the database, but you still need the customer record because it is referenced by old invoices (which may have a much longer lifespan).

Based on this the best solution is often the "IsDeleted" type of column, combined with a view (Quassnoi has mentioned partitioning, which can help with performance issues that might pop up due to a lot of invisible data).

Answer (score 0):

You can partition your tables on the `DELETED` column and define the views which would include the condition:

```
… AND deleted = 0
```

This will make the queries over the active data just as simple and efficient.

Comment: abhinav wants to delete rows ... so that would need to be horizontal partitioning.

Comment: Partitioning and using the views (in `SQL Server` and `Oracle`) will make the queries act exactly as if the rows were physically deleted from the tables. And to work with the deleted (or aggregated) data you can always write less simple queries directly against the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you were using SqlServer you can use triggers, which will allow you to move the record to a deleted table.

Comment: SQL Server isn't the the only database with a trigger feature, but it would help to know if Abhinav is using an RDBMS which supports triggers. Others I can think of are MySQL, Oracle, Progress OpenEdge, and probably others.

Comment: If that version has triggers, then yes, it should. Im sorry, i use Sql Server, so i am not sure about the version you are using.

Comment: Triggers are only available in MySQL 5+.